# Select the first matching down the tree among sibling divs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-traversal

Suppose I have

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="z"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="z"></div>
</div>
```

On Click of `.y` I need to select `.z` which is first one down the order.
What should I write after

```
$(this). ?
```

Where `this` is the `div` I have clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's `nextAll` and `first` functions:

```
var z = $(this).nextAll('.z').first();
```

Learn more:

https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

https://api.jquery.com/first/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nextAll()` method like following.

```
$(this).nextAll('.z:first')
```

Answer (score 0):

.next() will select from the tree downwards, .closest() will search for closest ancestors, try:

```
$(this).next("div.z");
```